# Errors after running Hyperloop sample app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I tried to run the Hyperloop Sample app but, even if it compiles fine, I get lots of errors anytime I tap any of the tableview cells:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 26;
[ERROR] :      line = 7;
[ERROR] :      message = "Can't find variable: Hyperloop";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/sportgoofy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC1AEB23-14C4-44A2-9790-7025AB7BE76F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/68239ABB-3492-4A9F-8F45-7C98F710B230/Hyperloop_Sample.app/hyperloop/uikit/uilabel.js";
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  Script Error Module "hyperloop/uikit/uilabel" failed to leave a valid exports object
[ERROR] :  ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of modal controller
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 26;
[ERROR] :      line = 7;
[ERROR] :      message = "Can't find variable: Hyperloop";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/sportgoofy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC1AEB23-14C4-44A2-9790-7025AB7BE76F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/68239ABB-3492-4A9F-8F45-7C98F710B230/Hyperloop_Sample.app/hyperloop/localauthentication/lacontext.js";
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  Script Error Module "hyperloop/localauthentication/lacontext" failed to leave a valid exports object
[ERROR] :  ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of modal controller
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 26;
[ERROR] :      line = 7;
[ERROR] :      message = "Can't find variable: Hyperloop";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/sportgoofy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC1AEB23-14C4-44A2-9790-7025AB7BE76F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/68239ABB-3492-4A9F-8F45-7C98F710B230/Hyperloop_Sample.app/hyperloop/uikit/uiview.js";
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  Script Error Module "hyperloop/uikit/uiview" failed to leave a valid exports object
[ERROR] :  ErrorController is up. ABORTING showing of modal controller
```

What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran into https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20469 which has been fixed recently. We hope to have a new HL beta out this week.

Comment: I hope you fix it soon, I was really interested in Hyperloop, mainly to use it with PayPal native SDK